# Constants declared in a function, Best practices?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, constants

Is there anything inherently wrong with declaring a constant inside a function if that constant is only pertinent to the running of that function?

as a quick example, instead of doing this:

```
 private const PROGRESS_BAR_MAX_VALUE:Number = 110;

 private function checkProgress():void
 {
     if(progress >= PROGRESS_BAR_MAX_VALUE)
        {
            do.something();
        }
    }
```

I would write this:

```
private function checkProgress():void
{
    const MAX_VALUE:Number = 110;

    if(progress >= MAX_VALUE)
    {
        do.something();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fair enough. I'm only asking because I've never thought twice about doing it until I found that Scaleform throws a runtime error if it hits a constant declared in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is absolutely nothing wrong with that.

You **should** use `CONST` whenever the value will never change. This makes your code easier to maintain and even saves a little memory, I've heard.

You should declare a variable in your function if it will only be used within the scope of that function.

So if you are creating a variable that will never change and should be used only in one function, you can declare `const MAX_VALUE` in your function.

Answer (score 4):

Two reasons not to declare constants inside functions:

1. Usually constants are meaningful. Even if you think that it will not be used outside the function, you are probably wrong.  Remember those stupid mx_internal paddings in text controls which are absolutely necessary to take into account for precise text measuring and layout. 
   It is very common to change private constant to public in practice. If you need another implementation for same area of responsibility, you will likely use same constants. If a class uses this value somehow, external classes often need it to predict its behavior. In your case this value may turn into a function parameter, in which case it shall be declared as a parameter with default value, not like a constant.
2. ActionScript is often not a first programming language that person learns, and people still have to use other languages while working mainly with ActionScript. People expect to see constant on class level, not on function-level. So, it is confusing for most of the people to see a constant inside a function.

In addition, make sure that your value is really a constant. If it is some text for a label, what if you have to add localization? If it is some delay option, what if they need to read it from config file? Your 'progress bar max value' does not look like a subject for a constant at all.

Comment: I upvoted this 10 years ago and I can see now that this was not a good answer. Anyone coming to this should ignore this advice when programming anything.